# Ansistrano deploy (privat github repository)

Tags: github, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my application to server via github repository and I get error.
[image]

How can I fix it? Help me please
Repository private and public key set in github settings

Answer (score 0):

Hard to help without the content of your deploy config file, but most likely Ansistrano is not using the right ssh key or there is an error on your config file.